# Error(30,11): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol UPDATE error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

While creating below SP I am getting the error as

> Error(30,11): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UPDATE" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null select with          continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date       pipe

Here is my SP

```
Procedure Update_Link_Details (
 P_UDLINKID NVARCHAR2,
 P_FOLDERSTRUCTURE NVARCHAR2,
 TBL_UPD OUT SYS_REFCURSOR        
)
 AS
 BEGIN
    OPEN TBL_UPD FOR 
         Update Tb_Link_Print 
          set status='Start' 
          where LINKPRINTID= P_UDLINKID 
          and upper(FOLDERSTRUCTURE) LIKE '%' || upper(P_FOLDERSTRUCTURE) || %';    
  NULL;
END Update_Link_Details;
```

Comment: are you trying to query data or change it? your cursor should be a SELECT, not an update. or, it shouldn't be a cursor to begin with.

Comment: Which one is it to be; Oracle or MySQL ?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: I just want to update the table with that status, i dont want select or something like that

Comment: @BriteSponge: it is `Oracle SQL developer`

Comment: then just use an update, you don't need the OPEN FOR bits. But you have an OUT SYS_REFCURSOR variable for your sp, so it looks like you want to return some data?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: without using that too, I am getting the error as `Error(34,21): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ; ` Also I want to return the updated record

Comment: You have a single quote missing around the last % and you should look at the RETURNING INTO clause to see if that will cover what you want to return.

Comment: good catch @BriteSponge, I didnt' scroll right far enough :)

Comment: Behold the power of the CR key!

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - TOAD takes the credit. I paste queries in and then use the formatter to read a prettier version.

Comment: @BriteSponge - don't tell Jeff you use TOAD :)

Comment: if you're using Oracle Database that's the most important thing. we have a new formatter in SQLDev now FWIW

Comment: @APC - ahem . . . well . . . yes. There are other very capable Oracle Development tools ! ! !

Answer (score 1):

> "I just want to update the table with that status ...Also I want to return the updated record"

That's two things, so it's two statements:

```
Procedure Update_Link_Details (
 P_UDLINKID NVARCHAR2,
 P_FOLDERSTRUCTURE NVARCHAR2,
 TBL_UPD OUT SYS_REFCURSOR        
)
 AS
 BEGIN
     Update Tb_Link_Print 
      set status='Start' 
      where LINKPRINTID= P_UDLINKID 
      and upper(FOLDERSTRUCTURE) LIKE '%' || upper(P_FOLDERSTRUCTURE) || '%';    
  OPEN TBL_UPD FOR 
   select * from  Tb_Link_Print 
   where LINKPRINTID= P_UDLINKID 
      and upper(FOLDERSTRUCTURE) LIKE '%' || upper(P_FOLDERSTRUCTURE) || '%';    
END Update_Link_Details;
```

This is a trifle clunky. Here is a version which engineers away the duplication:

```
Procedure Update_Link_Details (
 P_UDLINKID NVARCHAR2,
 P_FOLDERSTRUCTURE NVARCHAR2,
 TBL_UPD OUT SYS_REFCURSOR        
)
 AS
      upd_rowids sys.dbms_debug.vc2coll;
 BEGIN
     Update Tb_Link_Print 
      set status='Start' 
      where LINKPRINTID= P_UDLINKID 
      and upper(FOLDERSTRUCTURE) LIKE '%' || upper(P_FOLDERSTRUCTURE) || '%'
      returning rowidtochar(rowid) bulk collect into upd_rowids;    

  OPEN TBL_UPD FOR 
   select p.* 
   from  Tb_Link_Print p
   join table(upd_rowids) u
      on p.rowid = chartorowid(u.column_value) 
   ;    
END Update_Link_Details;
```

It uses the RETURNING clause to capture the ROWIDs of the affected rows, then opens the Ref Cursor using those ROWIDs to restrict the result set.